# iPhone USB connection

Tags: 14.04

when I plug in iphone 6 (USB) I get this message  "unable to mount iPhone,  unhandled lockdown error(3)". I'm running 32bit Ubuntu 14.04 and HP G62 laptop.
  I am new to Ubuntu and Linux.  I have not picked up a copy of "Linux For Dummies" yet.

Comment: How 'new' is the iPhone?  What iOS version is on it?

Comment: iOS 11.3  I upgraded to Ubuntu 16.5 , software is up to date.  Shotwell sees the Iphone but will not download photos to the computer.